# Problema en JUnit (pruebas unitarias)

Tags: java, junit, pruebas-unitarias

necesito probar un método con JUnit y dada la naturaleza de las clases no se como implementar una solución adecuada a ello:

```
public class Medidor implements calculosMedidor{
public ArrayList<AparatoElectrico> aparatos;
private double wattsConsumidos;
private double dinero;

public Medidor(int horas){
    aparatos=new ArrayList<>();
    wattsConsumidos=wattsConsumidos(horas);
    this.dinero=obtenerDinero(horas);

}

@Override
public double wattsConsumidos(int horas) {
    double wattsTotales=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < aparatos.size(); i++) {
        if(aparatos.get(i).isEncendido()){
            wattsTotales=wattsTotales+aparatos.get(i).getPotencia();
        }else{
            wattsTotales=wattsTotales+aparatos.get(i).getConsumoPasivo();
        }
    }

    double calculo=wattsTotales*horas;

    return calculo;
}
```

El método en cuestión es "wattsConsumidos", como pueden ver utiliza los elementos del ArrayList atributo "aparatos" para sacar los cálculos posteriores y luego devolver un resultado.

Luego tengo la siguiente prueba unitaria para probar el método "wattsConsumidos":

```
public class MedidorTest {
//Primero colocar los atributos que utilizaremos en todas las pruebas
static ArrayList<AparatoElectrico> aparatos;
static double wattsConsumidos;
static double dinero;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() {
    //Aca debo instanciar los atributos
    aparatos=new ArrayList<AparatoElectrico>();
    AparatoResistivo plancha=new AparatoResistivo(1000,200); 
    AparatoInductivo aspiradora=new AparatoInductivo(675,150);
    Electronico televisor=new Electronico(760,50);
    aparatos.add(plancha);
    aparatos.add(aspiradora);
    aparatos.add(televisor);
}

@Test
public void testWattsConsumidos() {
    System.out.println("wattsConsumidos");
    int horas = 4;
    Medidor instance = new Medidor(4);
    double expResult = 1600;
    double result = instance.wattsConsumidos(horas); //*He aquí el problema
    assertEquals(expResult, result, 0.0);
}
```

Ahora si ejecuto la prueba unitaria me dice que la prueba falló:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La explicación es que cuando llamo al método "wattsConsumidos" utiliza el ArrayList de la clase principal y no el de la prueba unitaria, entonces la misma prueba unitaria realiza los cálculos con el ArrayList de la clase principal que no posee ningún objeto, cuando lo que requería era que utilizara los objetos que había instanciado en la misma prueba unitaria en el @BeforeClass, pero no se como hacer que eso ocurra conservando la idea de que una prueba unitaria es un código de prueba con parámetros flexibles para, valga la redundancia probar un método en cuestión. Gracias por llegar hasta acá, espero haber explicado el problema con claridad!

Comment: Lo que sucede es porque no tienes asignado tu lista de aparatos creados en el Test, tiene de asignarlos `instance.aparatos = aparatos;`  ahora lo mejor seria que la lista de la Clase Medidor aparatos fuera privada y que el constructor sea de la siguiente forma `public Medidor(ArrayList<AparatoElectrico> aparatos, int horas)` así te obligarías a crear la Clase Medidor con su respectiva lista de aparatos en lugar de crear la instancia y tener que asignar en algún momento si te acuerdas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si solamente eres tester y no puedes corregir el código....

El problema con tu prueba unitaria es más de tipo lógico, no porque una variable se llame igual quiere decir que es la misma que otra.

Agregaste los aparatos a una lista, pero esa lista podemos decir que es `MedidorTest.aparatos` y en tu prueba unitaria, al llamar al constructor de Medidor se crea una nueva lista llamada `Medidor.aparatos`.

A esta notación se le conoce com nombre totalmente calificado, y en este caso como verás ambas variables son distintas.

En tu clase bajo prueba `Medidor` te recomiendo ponerle un **setter** y modificar tu prueba de la siguiente manera:

```
@Test
public void testWattsConsumidos() {
    System.out.println("wattsConsumidos");
    int horas = 4;
    Medidor instance = new Medidor(4);
    instance.setAparatos(MedidorTest.aparatos); // aquí le pasamos los aparatos antes de hacer el cálculo
    double expResult = 1600;
    double result = instance.wattsConsumidos(horas); //*He aquí el problema
    assertEquals(expResult, result, 0.0);
}
```

Ahora si tu eres el desarrollador y no el tester, modifica tu código para que tenga otro constructor que te reciba tanto las horas como los aparatos, es un mejor diseño ya que evita estos estados inconsistentes de la especificación Java Bean (que originalmente fue pensada para interfaces gráficas), otra forma de prevenirte problemas en la creación de tus objetos es usar el patrón de diseño de tipo creacional llamado builder.

¿Por qué este choro mareador?

Porque tienes problemas de creación, básicamente tu lista de aparatos actualmente siempre está vacía y aunque la modifiques externamente tu dinero siempre al crearse tu objeto será cero sin importar tus wats consumidos, el agregarle un builder te permitiría un diseño basado en el primer principio de SOLID, que es la separación de responsabilidades, es decir, poner el cálculo del precio aparte de la creación de tu objeto y también del cálculo de wats por hora. Así al depurar te será más fácil modificar cada aspecto sin impactar en lo otros. Estas prácticas de arquitectura  o [ingenieria-del-software](/questions/tagged/ingenieria-del-software) normalmente se aprenden con el tiempo y práctica, pero aplicarlas desde el principio puede ahorrarte muchos dolores de cabeza.